# Unity3d setup main menu for standalone OSX app

Tags: unity-game-engine

How setup main menu for standalone OSX applications (About "Project Name")? And setup Help dialog that appears after click about.
I want to change information in this dialog http://joxi.ru/Q2KV0e8fg0d0mj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer on my question http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/46339/how-to-change-about-dialog-for-standalone-builds.html?sort=oldest

You cannot setup About Dialog for OSX application. You can replace MainMenu.nib file (edit from xcode) but copyright information(about physics, mono, unity) you should leave in dialog;